# Converting a formatted date to another in PHP

Tags: php

I've a date in this format: Tuesday 11th October, 2016
stored in a php varaible $pastdate

I want to convert this to:
2016-10-11 23:59:59

I'm using this line of code:

```
$newDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($pastDate)).' 23:59:59';
```

However, the output of $newDate is:
2017-10-17 23:59:59

Can anyone explain why this is happening and how I should better format my code? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure there isn't something else going on? This works just fine for me.

Comment: `$newDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('l dS F, Y', $pastDate, new DateTimezone('UTC'))->setTime(23, 59, 59)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here we are changing date from one format to another. [`Date format reference`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/812423)

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$date=date_create_from_format("l dS F, Y", 'Tuesday 11th October, 2016');
$newDate= $date->format("Y-m-d");
echo $newDate." 23:59:59";
```

**Output:** `2016-10-11 23:59:59`

Comment: this has worked perfectly for my needs. I can see where I was going wrong now - thanks. Other solutions below look great too - thanks for your time :-)

Answer (score 0):

use the date function and pass the parameters for hour, minute and second to get the complete date and time

```
$newDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($pastDate));
```